# Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, ember.js

I'm new to ember.js and this is my first application. I want to build a login form in which if the user has passed in the right email and password, he should be transitioned to the home page. I am not sure whether I should use Ember Data for the login part but I read somewhere that Ember Data is not suitable for this specific login task so I should make ajax request (Is this assumption right ?). However, when I made the request I received the following error :

Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined at LoginComponent.logUser

I have made the http request in a login component class but I am not sure whether I should use a controller for this part as in all the examples I have seen the request was handled in controllers. However, I do not know how to use the login controller on a click on the login button.

So I have a few more questions apart from how to handle the error that I have:

1. Should I use Ember Data (if yes how) for the login task or should I use the ajax method?
2. What is the difference between a controller and component(the class) and when I should use each of them user clicks on handling data or making request as in this case?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is my code

login.hbs - template:

```
<h1 id="pageTitle">Log In</h1>
<Login/>
```

login.hbs - component:

```
<form {{on "submit" this.logUser}} id="login">
    <label class='formElement labelLogin'>Email :</label><br>
    <Input class='formElement input' @value={{this.email}}/><br>
    <label class='formElement labelLogin'>Password :</label><br>
    <Input class='formElement input' @value={{this.password}}/><br>
    <button id="loginButton" class='button formElement' type="submit">Log In</button> 
</form>
```

login.js - component class

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";

export default class LoginComponent extends Component{
  @tracked email;
  @tracked password;

  @action
  logUser(){
        let userData = JSON.stringify({
            'email' : this.email,
            'password' : this.password
        });
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url : 'https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/login',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : userData,
        }).then(() => {
            alert('Logged In');
            this.transitionToRoute('home');
        }).catch(function(error){
            alert(`Error: ${error}`);
        });
    }
}
```

routes.js:

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from 'gara6/config/environment';

export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('home');
});
```

Here is the edited login.js component class using fetch :

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";

export default class LoginComponent extends Component{
  @tracked email;
  @tracked password;

  @action
  logUser(){
        let userData = {
            'email' : this.email,
            'password' : this.password
        };
        let fetchObject = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'application/json', 
            },
            body : JSON.stringify(userData),
        };
        fetch('https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/login',fetchObject)
        .then(response => {
            alert(response.status);
            alert(response.statusText);
            if(!response.ok){
                alert('Network response was not ok');
            }
            alert(response.json());
            return response.json();
            // alert('Logged In');
            // this.transitionToRoute('home');
        }).then(data =>{
            alert(data);
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(`There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ${error}`);//This is the only alert that shows up.
        });
        console.log(userData);
    }
}
```

[Here I have clicked on the button and the alert shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn69H.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxeC.png):[This is the request data for the red login request. Surprisingly, there is request payload which matches the content of my text fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHcco.png)

[Here is what is shown when I click OK on the alert. The number of requests have changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxeC.png)

[This is the request data for the newly shown login request (note his type is GET)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upy8P.png)

Comment: reg, ajax: If you are using the latest version (Octane), JQuery integration is disabled by default. you can enable the feature in the `config/optional-features.json` file. Check this to learn more about optional features: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/optional-features/ . alternatively, you can use `ember-fetch` which is being included in the blueprint itself.

Comment: Even if you want to use jQuery instead of native `fetch`, I would recommend to import `jquery` explicitly and not rely on the Ember integration. Ember's jQuery integration is very likely to be deprecated and removed in short- to mid-term. Importing jQuery as any other dependency should continue to work long-term. But I _think_ native `fetch` is the way forward.

Comment: also you definitly *should not* use ember-data for a login but you could check out `ember-simple-auth` for this. However for registration `fetch` is the way to go.

Comment: @jelhan, you mean that if I enable jQuery in the config/optional-features.json as suggested by Gokul Kathirvel , this will not be of good use in the future. So I should import it as dependency.

Comment: @Lux,@jelhan,@Gokul Kathirvel , as all of you suggested I tried making the request using fetch. I had no idea that I could use fetch for post request. However, the request is still not working. As I go to inspect my request in the networks tab in the chrome developer tools I see a GET request made. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it. I will edit my question with some screenshots and the new code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a friend of mine the problem of POST request converting into GET has been solved. Turns out that the issue has occurred from the form element, which has predefined functions by default, so the solution is to prevent them using e.preventDefault().

Here is the already working code:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";

export default class LoginComponent extends Component{
  @tracked email;
  @tracked password;
  @service router;
  
  @action
  logRequest(){
    let result=0;
    let userData = {
        'email' : this.email,
        'password' : this.password
    };
    let fetchObject = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json', 
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(userData),
    };
    fetch('https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/login',fetchObject)
        .then(response => {
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            result=1;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(`There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ${error}`);
        });
    return result;
  }


  @action
  logUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        let result = this.logRequest;
        if(result){
            alert('Logged in');
            this.router.transitionTo('home');
        }
        else{
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    }
}
```